# Calendar add date programmatically

Tags: views, datetime

I am having a bit of trouble figuring out a thing with Drupal Calendar.

I have created a custom content type , with a `date` field.
I display the dates as events in a Calendar style view.

I want to add custom "event" on the day(s) after this event,based on some PHP logic.
What would be a starting place to start modfitying it  ?

For example: I insert 26th of May as a date (in a node of my custom content type).
If the day is Saturday, I want the next day to be also marked in the calendar.

Answer (score 1):

Since the event is a content type. You could use [hook_cron](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7) to find expired events and add new event node.

**Add node programmatically.**

```
  $body_text = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.';

  $node = new stdClass();
  $node->type = 'article';
  node_object_prepare($node);

  $node->title    = 'Node Created Programmatically on ' . date('c');
  $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;

  $node->body[$node->language][0]['value']   = $body_text;
  $node->body[$node->language][0]['summary'] = text_summary($body_text);
  $node->body[$node->language][0]['format']  = 'filtered_html';

  $path = 'content/my-lipsum-' . date('YmdHis');
  $node->path = array('alias' => $path);

  node_save($node);
```

[How to programmatically create node in drupal 7](http://www.lightrains.com/blog/programmatically-create-node-drupal-7)

Comment: This might help me continuing my progress. 
I just have to create the back-end logic so it suit my needs. Thank you !